# Macro for check T

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not really good in creating macros, that's why looking help here. What I'm trying to do is to check from column G (start from 3rd row) times if the difference between two cells is more than 5 min than leave both two rows and go to next row if it is no, delete upper one and go to the next row.

Let's say check 1 against 2

```
           2 ------- 3
           3 ------- 4
           4 ------- 5
           5 ------- 6
           6 ------- until empty cell
```

1. 22:35:00  delete
2. 22:35:25  delete
3. 22:35:07  Leave
4. 22:48:31  Leave
5. 22:48:38  delete
6. 22:49:35  delete

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Macro()
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("G3")
    Do
        Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)

        If r - r.Offset(-1, 0) < TimeSerial(0, 5, 0) Then
            r.Offset(-1, 0).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
        Else
            Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Loop While r <> ""
End Sub
```

If you don't want to remove the cells but only clear them then replace the line

`r.Offset(-1, 0).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp`

by

`r.Offset(-1, 0) = ""`

Comment: Thank you, woks how should be ;)